# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fuad.traffic/com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

i have problem i want make map but there is problem and this is my problem. when i click my 
aplication, my application force close unfortunetaly. so please help me thank's

in log cat

this my eror

```
01-04 21:48:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(31063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-04 21:48:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(31063): Process: com.fuad.traffic, PID: 31063
    01-04 21:48:53.218: E/AndroidRuntime(31063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fuad.traffic/com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this my code

androidmaniefest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
         <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBa_hCEM7hDQG6YoWmV-_gIGfGAnL55j4o"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

this is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
/**static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(37.029869, -76.345222);
MapView mapView;?*/

ArrayList<LatLng>mMarkerPoints;
double mLatitude =0;
double mlongitude = 0;
GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
RadioGroup rgViews = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_views);

rgViews.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(checkedId == R.id.rb_normal){
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_satelite){
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
}
}
});
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

int requestCode = 10;
Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
dialog.show();
}else {
mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 googleMap = fm.getMap();
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

if (location!=null){
onLocationChanged(location);
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please post the **entire** stack trace, and point out the lines in your code that correspond to that stack trace. That will make it a lot easier for people here at Stack Overflow to help you with your problem.

In this case, you are attempting to use `googleMap` before you initialize it. Move `googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)` to some point after you have called `googleMap = fm.getMap();`.

Also, please bear in mind that `getMap()` is deprecated in the current version of Maps V2, in favor of `getMapAsync()`. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2) contains many sample projects demonstrating the use of Maps V2, all of which have been updated to use `getMapAsync()`.

Comment: oh yes, i found my else. thanx @CommonsWare